# How to create automatic follow-up (delayed) animation for child objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, parent

I have a parent object with several child objects. I would like to animate the parent object with child objects following up with slightly delayed time. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Slow Parent* Option available in the object relations properties.

[image]

After setting up you parent/child chain of objects go to each object individually and under the *Properties Window > Object > Relations Extras* tick *Slow Parent* option. Bellow it set the desired delay in frames.

[image]

You can select all relevant objects and click the properties wile pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to set the values for several selected objects at once. Alternatively right click and choose *Copy to Selected*.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any equivalent in Blender 2.8? Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly slow parent has been removed from 2.8,perhaps it is worth asking a new question about it